# PHP : Ganon get html of a block

Tags: php, dom, html-parsing, ganon

I am working with ganon dom parser for HTML parsing and trying to get the content from a DIV block but for some reason the returned object is not working, below is my code and i am using :

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);
#Include the dom parser lib.
require_once('ganon.php');

$html = file_get_dom('http://jlc.watchprosite.com/?show=forumpost&amp;fi=2&amp;pi=1818820&amp;ti=279373&amp;msid=&amp;s=');
print_r($html("div[id='sidebar']")->childCount());

?>
```

This gives

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function childCount() on a non-object in D:\xampp\htdocs\govberg\test.php on line 7
```

When i do `print_r($html)` it is printing a large object.

Anyboby able to point out whats going wrong..

Comment: did you check whether $html contains `div['id=sidebar']`? Perhaps the selector can't find it and return a null object.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like,

```
if ($html("div[id='sidebar']",0)){ // or use # like if ($html("div#sidebar",0)){
    echo 'Total children are '.$html("div[id='sidebar']",0)->childCount();
}
```